# WPF slider seek to clicked position

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

the default slider behavior is when clicked after the point it ticks by some value, and when clicked before the point is does the opposite. I wish it to behave like in windows media player, when I click position it will jump to it. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably aren't setting [Slider.IsMoveToPointEnabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.slider.ismovetopointenabled.aspx). With this being set to `True`, the `Slider` should move to the point clicked

```
<Slider Width="200"
        IsMoveToPointEnabled="True"
        Maximum="1000"
        Minimum="0" />
```